# Pass data from ng-template to it's parent component Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a parent component which has ng-template as a child. This lets me dynamically inject different components into ng-template. 
Now, I need to pass data from a component that is being injected into ng-template to the parent component. In normal scenario where there is no ng-template, I would use Event Emitter. However, I don't think ng-template supports that.

What would be the best way to pass data from ng-template to it's parent?

Below is code of the parent component:

```
<div id="modal">
  <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="close-button uw-icon-close-x" (click)="closeModal()" >
</div>
    <ng-template #modalAnchor></ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use @ViewChild to get access to ng-template data from parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service to communicate between components.